# I want to execute the command with multiple argument on ssh using python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

What I tried is to execute :

```
host=xyz
port = 22
username = xyz_username
ssh_cli = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_cli.connect(host, port, username, allow_agent=False, timeout=None)

commands = [./BinaryExecutableFile  ./scene00021.bin ./scene00021.json  ./param.txt   ./cluster.json    ./count.json]
                        
for command in commands:
    ssh.client.exec_command(command)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

terms

- Binary file:BinaryExecutableFile
- input file:./scene00021.bin output
- output_file:./scene00021.apk
- paramaters file1: ./param.txt
- paramaters file2:./cluster.json
- paramaters file3: ./count.json

Comment: You're missing quotes around the elements of `commands` and commas between them.

Comment: Why are you looping through `commands` if it's not a list of different commands?

Comment: actually there are multiple commands to execute which I didn't add while posting question

Comment: ok I will try and add quotes and comma

Comment: Then edit the question and show what you actually want to do. And post it with correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. There's just one command with multiple arguments. Concatenate them together to make the command line, and execute that.

```
ssh.client.exec_command(' '.join(commands))
```

Comment: actually some of the entries in argument change at run time thats why not using join command...to be more specific list of entries are there which change the name of .bin and .apk

Comment: Why can't you use `join()` when the arguments change?